# Laravel notification , problem with displaying the notification in real-time

Tags: laravel, notifications, broadcast, pusher, laravel-echo

Hello i have a problem with Laravel notification in real-time. I have done anything like the docs says but still I have to refresh the page for receiving the notification.
Here is my Controller for evaluation: ( I have to notify all the users when a evaluation has been created). I'm using Pusher and Echo for that, I have tried multiple solutions for it, but no answer yet.

```
  public function store(Request $request )
{
    //dd($request);
    $data = request()->validate([
      'expert' => 'required',
      'gram1' => 'required',
      'karate1' => 'required',
      
      
    ]);
    //Create Post
    $evaluation = new Evaluation;
    
    $evaluation->expert = $request->input('expert');
    $evaluation->gram1 = $request->input('gram1');
    $evaluation->gram2 = $request->input('gram2');
    $evaluation->gram3 = $request->input('gram3');
    $evaluation->gram4 = $request->input('gram4');
    $evaluation->karate1 = $request->input('karate1');
    $evaluation->karate2 = $request->input('karate2');
    $evaluation->karate3 = $request->input('karate3');
    $evaluation->karate4 = $request->input('karate4');
    $evaluation->pietre1 = $request->input('pietre1');
    $evaluation->pietre2 = $request->input('pietre2');
    $evaluation->pietre3 = $request->input('pietre3');
    $evaluation->pietre4 = $request->input('pietre4');
    $evaluation->aur_prelucrat1 = $request->input('aur_prelucrat1');
    $evaluation->aur_prelucrat2 = $request->input('aur_prelucrat2');
    $evaluation->aur_prelucrat3 = $request->input('aur_prelucrat3');
    $evaluation->aur_prelucrat4 = $request->input('aur_prelucrat4');
    $evaluation->pret_per_gram1 = $request->input('pret_per_gram1');
    $evaluation->pret_per_gram2 = $request->input('pret_per_gram2');
    $evaluation->pret_per_gram3 = $request->input('pret_per_gram3');
    $evaluation->pret_per_gram4 = $request->input('pret_per_gram4');
    $evaluation->verighta = $request->input('verighta');
    $evaluation->cercei = $request->input('cercei');
    $evaluation->inel_B = $request->input('inel_B');
    $evaluation->Inel_D = $request->input('Inel_D');
    $evaluation->bratara = $request->input('bratara');
    $evaluation->lant = $request->input('lant');
    $evaluation->piatra_pretioasa = $request->input('piatra_pretioasa');
    $evaluation->medalion = $request->input('medalion');
    $evaluation->cruce = $request->input('cruce');
    $evaluation->monede = $request->input('monede');
    $evaluation->altceva = $request->input('altceva');
    $evaluation->Nr_obiecte = $request->input('Nr_obiecte');
    $evaluation->suma_imprumut = $request->input('suma_imprumut');
    $evaluation->evaluare = $request->input('evaluare');
    $evaluation->descriere = $request->input('descriere');
    $evaluation->user()->associate($request->user());
    $evaluation->save();

  //  $test = Evaluation::find($evaluation->id);
    $users = User::all();

    // Notification::send($users, new EvaluationNotify($evaluation));
        broadcast(new \App\Notifications\EvaluationNotify($evaluation))->toOthers();

   
    //User::find(Auth::user()->id )->notify(new EvaluationNotify($test));
   // User::find(Auth::user()->id )->notify(new EvaluationNotify($evaluation));
   


    return redirect('/evaluation')->with('success', 'evaluation Created');

}`enter code here`
```

Here are my routes :

```
    Route::get('/', function () {

    return view('welcome');
});





Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('users', 'UserController');

Route::resource('roles', 'RoleController');

Route::resource('permissions', 'PermissionController');

Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');

Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');

Route::resource('client', 'ClientController');

Route::resource('evaluation', 'EvaluationController');



Route::post('/notification/get', 'NotificationController@get');

Route::post('/notification/read', 'NotificationController@read');
```

Here is my app.js file

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#main-wrapper',
data: {
    notifications: ''
},
mounted() {
    Axios.post('/notification/get').then(response => {
        this.notifications = response;
    });
 
    var userId = $('meta[name="userId"]').attr('content');
    window.Echo.private('App.User.' + userId)
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log('hello');
        
    });
}
```

})

This is my evaluation

```
namespace App\Notifications;


use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use App\Evaluation;
use App\User;

class EvaluationNotify extends Notification 
{
  use Queueable;
  public $evaluation;
  /**
   * Create a new notification instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct(Evaluation $evaluation)
  {
      $this->evaluation = $evaluation;
  }

  /**
   * Get the notification's delivery channels.
   *
   * @param  mixed  $notifiable
   * @return array
   */
  public function via($notifiable)
  {
      return ['database', 'broadcast'];
  }


  /**
   * Get the array representation of the notification.
   *
   * @param  mixed  $notifiable
   * @return array
   */
  public function toDatabase($notifiable)
  {
      return [
          'evaluation' => $this->evaluation->id,
          
      ];
  }

  public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
  {
      return new BroadcastMessage([
          'evaluation' => $this->evaluation->id,
      
      ]);     
  }
  
}
```

Here is my vue component

```
<template>

<div class="mt-2">
       <li v-for="notification in notifications.data" style="display:inline;">
             <a href="#" style="color:white; background-color:red; padding: 3px; margin:2px; font-size: 13px; border-radius:55%;" 
              v-on:click="MarkAsRead(notification)">{{notification.data.evaluation}}</a>          
       </li>
 </div>      
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:['notifications','evaluation', 'userId'],
        methods:{
            MarkAsRead : function(notification) {
                var data = {
                    id: notification.id
                };
                axios.post('/notification/read', data).then(response => {
                    window.location.href = "/evaluation/" + notification.data.evaluation + "/edit";
                });
                

                 },

       
        },
     
    }
    
    
    
</script>
```

And here is the method that i call it in view :

```
<h6 class="ml-2">
    <notification id="notifications" v-bind:notifications="notifications"></notification>   
</h6>
```

Comment: Do you have your ```queue:worker``` running in the background?

Comment: 'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),

 'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

Comment: I have read in docs that i have to set queue driver to sync, only that. Have I missed something ?

Comment: You have to run the queue worker: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker
You can use a Supervisor or a Deamon for it. But it have to run. The broadcasting only create the job in the database. The queue worker will dispatch it on the channel. At the moment, I think you have 0 log on pusher about notifications, because your server is not even trying to reach Pusher.

Comment: At first, I suggest you to try running ```php artisan queue:work``` into the terminal and check the output. Is it returning something?

Comment: If I go to my debug console in pusher and i listen to App.user. for notification it works, like i receive API messages for all my 3 users

Comment: Can you add your  ```routes/channels.php``` to the op?

Comment: Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});